# Export Eclipse RCP Product

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I'm trying to create an Eclipse RCP application; I exported this app but When i try to open my Eclipse RCP product I receive this problem in my logger file:

> !SESSION 2015-03-17 12:01:08.995 eclipse.buildId=unknown
>   java.version=1.7.0_71 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader
>   constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Command-line
>   arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-03-17 12:01:10.027 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: Application
>   "test.rcp.application" could not be found in the registry. The
>   applications available are:
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The stacktrace tells you the problem: `Application "test.rcp.application" could not be found in the registry`

Comment: hi, first step: i create a project plugin eclipse 3.5, second step: i adding "product configuration " to my project, third step : expoort project as eclipse product but i can't open my product after exporting I receive a problem in a Logger File . thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an Eclipse e4 application you specify `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application` as the Application in your xxx.product configuration file.

Use the product you defined in your RCP plugin.xml.

Comment: I have this code into my RCP plugin.xml                                      <plugin>
   <extension id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run  class="test.rcp.Application"> </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
<extension id="product_test" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product application="test.rcp.application" name="My Product">
    <property name="appName" value="My Product"> </property>
    <property name="applicationXMI" value="test.rcp/Application.e4xmi"> </property>
  </product>
</extension>
</plugin>

Comment: Is this an e4 application or are you trying to use the application model with an old style 3.x application?

Comment: I'm trying to use the application model with an old style 3.x application

Comment: In which case I can't help as I am not sure how that is set up. You will certainly need more features in your product file to include the 3.x compatibility code.

Comment: hi, first step: i create a project plugin eclipse 3.5, second step: i adding "product configuration " to my project, third step : expoort project as eclipse product but i can't open  my product after exporting  I receive a problem in a Logger File . thanks in advance